# React onChange Handler won't handle the change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend

my react typescript app has many inputs so i decided to write one universal onChange Handler. But it dont change anything in the frontend...

```
    function handleChange(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setForm({ ...form, [e.target.value]: value });
    console.log("Input changed with: " + value);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a typo-level mistake to me. Did you mean to use `name` instead of `value` in one of those two places? (E.g.: `const {name, value} = e.target; setForm({...form, [name]: value});`)  Currently you're using `value` both for the property name **and** its value by doing `{...form, [e.target.value]: value}`.

Comment: Side note: Whenever you're setting state based on existing state, it's safest to use the callback form of the state setter. So: `setForm((form) => ({...form, [name]: value}));`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Name should be a type of my interface and value should be the value to insert.

Comment: As I said re your comment on the answer below, please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). The above absolutely works if you have your inputs set up correctly (both `value` and `onChange`, where `value` comes from `form`). Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/9Ltq64cb/

Answer (score -1):

Here working code:

```
function handleChange(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    setForm({ ...form, [name]: value }); // <-- error was here, in brackets should be name
    console.log("Input changed with: " + value);
}
```

Comment: If it's that, really it's a typo-level error and the question should just be closed with a comment (which I've already posted).

Comment: Sorry, but the inputs are not working :(

Comment: @leomatic197 - Then please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: did you add name property to input element in jsx?